# PostgreSQL Date Conversion Function

Tags: function, postgresql, date-conversion

I have one challenge:

I have the following code in SQL Server and I want to move it to PostgreSQL DBMS.

[image: SQL Server Code]

I adapted it to PostgreSQL just like the following:

```
CREATE function public.SEMANA_ISO (fecha date) returns integer as $$ 
DECLARE 
    semana_ISO int= date_part ('week',fecha)+1
    -date_part('week',CAST(date_part('year',fecha) as CHAR(4)) + '0104');
BEGIN 
    IF (semana_ISO=0)
    THEN
    semana_ISO=public.SEMANA_ISO(CAST(date_part('year',fecha)-1
    AS CHAR(4)) + '12' + CAST(24 + date_part('day',fecha) AS CHAR(2)))+1;

    ELSIF ((date_part('month',fecha)=12) AND ((date_part('day',fecha)-date_part('day',fecha))>=28))
    THEN
    semana_ISO=1;

    END IF; 

RETURN semana_ISO;   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As you may see, I tried to make it look the most similar as in SQL Server is.
However when I try to run this function and test it:

```
Select public.SEMANA_ISO('28/12/2014');
```

The DMBS shows many errors:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character + unknown
LINE 2: ...rt('week',CAST(date_part('year',fecha) as CHAR(4)) + '0104')

HINT: No operator matches the name and type of the arguments. You may need to add explicit type casts. 
QUERY: SELECT date_part ('week', date) +1 
-date_part ('week', CAST (date_part ('year', date) as CHAR (4)) + '0104') 
CONTEXT: PL / pgSQL function semana_iso (date) at line 5 during initialization of local variables in the statement block
```

**What I try to do is the following. 
From the following input date format: dd/mm/yyyy I want to use the function above to show it as the next output format:mm-dd-yyyy**

I have thought in doing a simpler function that could receive the date in the format given (dd/mm/yyyy) and using the set datestyle = mdy statement change it in the body of the function and finally print it or return it.

What do you suggest folks?

Your help & time is always appreciated!

Comment: Actually for what purpose your using this `function/stored` procedure ? only you want to convert the `datestyle`??

Comment: To change the format of the date. From dd/mm/yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: ok for a specific item in a table or what ??

Comment: A `date` column *does **NOT*** have "a format". So there is no need to "change" it. And the string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+`. So `+ '12'` should be `|| '12'`. But it seems all you want is `to_char()` with an appropriate format mask.

Comment: I just want to show the date in different way. As you can see from the SQL Server it does do that. I want to enter the date as dd/mm/yyyy and then get it as mm-dd-yyyy. Including the dashes

Comment: a guess : you can try like this `select to_char(now(), 'mm-dd-yyyy');`

Comment: If you have a real `date` value, then all you need is `to_char()`. There is no need for your own function. If you store your dates in a `varchar` (which you ***really*** shouldn't be doing), you want a combination of `to_date()` and `to_char()` - still no reason for your own function

Comment: `select to_char(now(), 'mm-dd-yyyy');` will return the date in `mm-dd-yyyy` format, so that you can include that in your _func_ `select to_char(fecha , 'mm-dd-yyyy');` like this

Comment: Thanks! I will give your tips a try and let you know!

Comment: haha, is that a photograph of a screen?

Comment: Nope, that is a picture from a sheet of paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guess you may need a `Function` like below

```
CREATE function a_date_conv (fecha date) returns text as $$ 
select to_char(fecha, 'mm-dd-yyyy');  
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

> select a_date_conv('08/10/2014')

```
Result
-------
10-08-2014
```

Comment: Awesome, I was just finishing to code the function. Thanks for your help Winged Panther